# In Google Calendar, is there any way to add a task, rather than an event, via the Quick Add feature?

Tags: google-calendar, tasks

Quick Add is accessed by pressing `q` or clicking the down arrow on the `Create` button in the left column.

Comment: It doesn't look like it, but I'd love to be proven wrong. Tasks is overdue for some development love.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't quick add a task on the calendar. Only an event or appointment.